# Unable to shutdown redis-server even after uninstall

Tags: services, kill, redis

After uninstalling:

```
> ps aux | grep redis-server
root      147242  0.7  0.0  52968  7824 ?        Ssl  16:58   0:00 /snap/redis/137/usr/bin/redis-server *:6379
stavalfi  147321  0.0  0.0  17672   672 pts/0    S+   16:58   0:00 grep --color=auto redis-server
```

When I kill one of the pids (`kill <pid>` or `sudo service redis-server stop` or `sudo systemctl unmask redis-server.service && kill <pid>`), it is recreated with different pid.

How can I stop and remove redis from my machine?

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried turning the server off and on again? 

Comment: I tried to reinstall it again. I tried to start and stop it. What am I missing here?